# Is my way of returning negative 1 wrong, it will not output negative 1

Tags: java

```
public class MathMethods {
public static int GCD (int a, int b){
    int c;
    int d;
    d = -1;
    if (a < 0 || b < 0){
    return d;
    }else{

    while (b!=0){
        c=a%b;
        a=b;
        b=c;

    }
    return a;
    }




}
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println("GCD of 15 and 5: " + MathMethods.GCD(15,5));
    System.out.println("GCD of 12 and 18: " + MathMethods.GCD(12,18));
    System.out.println("GCD of 42 and 56: " + MathMethods.GCD(42,56));
    System.out.println("GCD of 126 and 84: " + MathMethods.GCD(126,84));
    System.out.println("GCD of 72390 and 15000: " + MathMethods.GCD(72390,15000));
}
}
```

My code for GCD is correct for what ever numbers i put in it returns an output. However Im trying to get if a negative number is put in then a negative 1 is output, but for some reason that fails.

Comment: What does it return with negative inputs?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `d`, though. You can just use `return -1;`

Comment: interesting so if you change one of the numbers like 15 and 5 for example to just -5 and 15 it outputs a negative 1?

Comment: because when i do that it does not work

Comment: What *does* it return?

Comment: Did you forget to recompile? It's working for me too.

Comment: this one working fine... check here http://ideone.com/zT1Vpt

Comment: interesting I just cant get it to work with what i have now you added in other packages?

Comment: What im running with now is on eclipse and if i change 5 and 15 to say -5 and 15 it still returns 5

Comment: nm face palm... got it thanks

Comment: Did you forget to recompile?

Comment: Side note: in Java your should throw an exception (usually `IllegalArgumentException`) if passed parameters are incorrect.